# Selenium Chrome Driver Unable to locate element INPUT

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, c#-3.0

ERROR:
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='label-input']//input"}

I need to send a Username to here
https://prnt.sc/sf9t14
https://prnt.sc/sfaqre

HELP ME PLEASE BROS :)

Comment: It would be easier to use the CSS selector method with selector like 'div.choose-nickname-view div.label-input input' or assign an id attribute to the input field and select it with id method.

Comment: If it was me, I'd make sure the input element had an id, then you can use `By.Id` rather than the mystery that is xpath.

Comment: Another print with CSS https://prnt.sc/sfaqre if you can help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist you have to switch the frame:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//iframe[@class='gameframe']")));
```

Then you can type the input

```
IWebElement userInput = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='label-input']/input"));
userInput.SendKeys("username");
```